# Sketch is not being received by Arduino even though Arduino Editor acts like it is finished?

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

In my attached screen capture the Arduino Editor appears to be performing the upload, however it never finishes. Completes three steps, the last being the sketch up-load and then states that it is busy.  Sorry that I can't submit a short video. [image: Up-Loader Busy]Please suggest ideas to solve this issue.  Maybe this is related to my first question?

Comment: there is no attempt to upload. it looks like Verify command, not Upload

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who have suggested corrective action for my posted communication problem. After trying all of the suggestions, I threw up my hands and deleted all evidence of Arduino Create Editor. Next I installed the Arduino Create Editor as a fresh/new install. Magically, all of my communication issues with the Arduino Uno have been corrected. Apparently, something in the communication code was corrupted during my first attempt install on my desktop PC.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you start with a simple blink example sketch and be sure it works. I believe it will. Your picture is almost impossible to read but i caught you have multiple libraries and several other problems. Look at the errors and resolve them one at a time. Until you do it will never load, that is the way it was designed. Be SURE there is only one file with the .ino extension unless it is also part of your sketch.

Comment: the screenshot shows successful compilation. so what about is this 'answer'?

Comment: I would suggest downloading the Arduino IDE and try that, it works great on linux mint. As far as the Amazon thing you might contact them for help. From what I can see it does not do the upload. The reason for the suggestion is to eliminate as many unknowns as possible.

Comment: the Amazon thing is the official Arduino Web IDE by Arduino. it is hosted on Amazon cloud